# Why can't I set the array value? why won't it cast the string?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, casting, non-static

```
Private Player[] players = new Player[2];
    private int currentPlayerIndex = 0;



    public Game(Form1 form)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++) {
            players[i] = (string)"Player"; }
```

I keep getting an error saying it cannont convert string to Player type...

Below is the player class, which also sets the property for Name...

```
class Player
{
    private string name = "";



    public  Player(string name)
    {
        name = "Player";

    }


    public string Name {
        get { return name; }

        set { name = value; }

    }
```

Comment: It should be player[i] = new Player(){ };

Comment: A `Player` is not a `System.String`. Maybe something like this: `players[i]=new Player{Name="Player"+i};` (presuming a `Name` property)

Comment: Hello @TimSchmelter I have added the Player class above. what do you think?

Comment: @diam: `players[i]=new Player("Player");`. Feel free to change the name of every player (f.e. as shown in my last comment).

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH @TimSchmelter !! if you post it as an answer ill mark yours answered. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Your constructor should assign the given name instead of the constant `"Player"` i.e `this.name = name;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`players` is an array of `Player` objects:

```
private Player[] players = new Player[2];
```

You're trying to put a string in the array.

```
players[i] = (string)"Player";
```

That does not work, you can only put an instance of `Player` in the array

```
players[i] = new Player("Player1");
```

Answer (score -2):

Because your code doesn't provide for an [implicit cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) from string to Player.  You need something like this:

```
public static implicit operator Player(string str)
{
    return new Player(str);
}
```

Of course then you will need a Player constructor that takes a string argument.

Edit: Changed explicit to implicit.  An implicit operator will cause the code to compile.

Comment: I provided a straightforward answer to the question.  `why won't it cast the string?`  In fact the compiler error says pretty clearly what the problem is `Cannot implicitly convert type string to Player` (I was wrong about using an explicit conversion)

Comment: The error is due to the lack of an implicit conversion but the fix is almost certainly to just assign an instance of the correct type into the array.

Comment: Straightforward is this: `players[i]=new Player("Player")` not suggesting to provide a conversion operator from type `A` to type `B`. That's  anything but straightforward. Most times it's just confusing and a source for nasty bugs.